# Approximating a random variable by a sequence of random variables

Tags: probability, approximation-theory

Consider the triangular hat function:

\begin{equation}
    \varphi(x) = 
    \begin{cases} 1 - |x|, & \text{if } x \in [-1, 1], \\ 0, & \text{otherwise.} \end{cases}
\end{equation}

It is well known that $\varphi$ is the pdf
$$Y = X_1 + X_2 - 1,$$
where each $X_i$ is a uniformly distributed random variable on $[0,1]$.

I am interested in the following question: is it possible to find a sequence of random variables, $X_n$, with *smooth* pdf supported $[-1,1]$ such that the pdfs of $X_n$ converges to the pdf of $Y$?

**Edit:** The motivation is that this function has shown up in a different non-probabilistic problem. In that context, I am looking for a preferably smooth function approximating $\varphi$.
The motivation to find a sequence is that I can use concentration inequalities to sharply bound error estimates.

Comment: $\varphi$ is not the ditribution of $Y$. It is the pdf of $\varphi$. Also, you have to take $X_1$ and $X_2$ independent.

Comment: Yes, correcting my typo.

Comment: What is wrong with  $X_n\equiv Y$?

Comment: The question makes sense only if you take a non-absolutely continuous random variable $Y$ and ask for its approximation by absolutely continuous random variables.

Comment: @geetha290krm Added some details.

Comment: $Y$ is itself abs. continuous. It is its own approximation.

Comment: @geetha290krm Clarified a bit more. I'm looking for a pdf that is smooth. At the end of the day, I just want a good smooth approximation to $\varphi$. The motivation for this slightly round about quetion is mentioned in the edit above.

Comment: Is this about approximating a pdf using a fuction which is a pdf itself? If you just need to have an appromation which is smooth (given that this seems to come from a different context), then turn to Fourier.

Comment: @geetha290krm It is about the former.

Answer (score 2):

Let $Z$ have  a smooth pdf concenetarted on $(-1,1)$, independent of $Y$ and consider $U_n=1_{|Y| \le 1-\frac  1n }Y+\frac Z n$. Then $U_n$ is absolutely continuous simply because $Z$ is absolutely continuous and independent of $1_{|Y| \le 1-\frac  1n }Y$. Clearly, $U_n \to Y$ a.s. and $|U_n| \le 1$.  Since convolution is a smoothing operation, the distribution of $U_n$ as smooth as the distribution of $Z$. This construction does not depend on the specific pdf $\varphi$.

Comment: Wouldn't you want to convolve with a sequence of smooth functions, $Z_n$, that concentrate at $0$ as $n$ goes to infinity? I want the *pdf* of $U_n$ to be smooth, not its distribution.

Comment: My construction is very general and it  does not rely on uniform distribution. I have edited my answer.  @user82261

Comment: Fair enough. This is exactly what I thought. Thanks! I thought of convolution before but then I got sidetracked by thinking about pdfs. But there's definitely a sequence of mollifiers/random variables that concentrate at $0$, so we're good.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the sequence given in @geetha290krm's answer, it may be easier to work with

$$U_n=\frac{n-1}{n}Y+\frac Z n$$

where $Z$ can have any arbitrary smooth distribution on the interval $(-1,1)$, which is independent of $Y$.

In this case, random sampling from $U_n$ is easier. Also, the pdf of $U_n$ is given by

$$f_{U_n(x)}=\int_{-1}^{1}f_{\frac Z n}(x-t) \text{d}F_{\frac{n-1}{n}Y}(t) \quad x \in [-1,1].$$